# Trigger inserting new row after update of another table in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I would like to create trigger which should create new row in table INVOICES after a new row is created in FREIGHTS table. The trigger should get value from table FREIGHTS and put it in column in table INVOICES.

For now it looks as follows:

```
create or replace TRIGGER NewInvoice
AFTER INSERT ON FREIGHTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO INVOICES(id, netvalue, grossvalue, tax, receipient)
 SELECT '1', '1', weight, '1', '1'
 FROM FREIGHTS
END;
```

The error is at the final END statement.

Thanks in advance for your support ;)

Comment: Try: `INSERT INTO INVOICES(id, netvalue, grossvalue, tax, receipient)
VALUES( '1', '1', :new.weight, '1', '1' );`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming weight is a column in FREIGHTS table:

```
create or replace TRIGGER NewInvoice
AFTER INSERT ON FREIGHTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO INVOICES(id, netvalue, grossvalue, tax, receipient)
  values ('1', '1', :new.weight, '1', '1');

END;
```

Maybe read the [docs?](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS20041)